# Executing some code after form closed in a Windows Form Application C#

Tags: c#, windows

I'm creating a C# Windows Form Application with a single form, which creates some files. But i want these to be temporary.

So what i intend to do is this.

All the files which are created during the program execution period will be deleted after the form closes(I tried to delete them before closing the form, but i get an error, so that's why i need to delete it after the form closes). But the problem is just cant seem to do it. I tried searching some websites but i couldn't get a solution.So here i am. If anyone knows how to execute some code after form closes ,pls share it with me

Thanks in advance.

----Edit----

Sry guys for not adding the code here.

Im a noob in application development.
Anyways,here's what i tried:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        int Length = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\Yamin").Length;
        for( int i = 0; i < Length; i++ )
        {
            File.Delete("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\Yamin\\" + i + ".jpg");
        }
    }
```

Also tried this :

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        int Length = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\Yamin").Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
        {
            File.Delete("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\Yamin\\" + i + ".jpg");
        }
    }
```

I start the program for testing. Everything works fine but when i close the form i expect the functions above to be executed, but they are not being executed.
Thats my problem.
Again, thanks in advance.

Comment: why can't you delete them during the normal processing / onClosing etc.. sounds like you are doing something wrong.. can you post the code in regards to how you are cleaning up the files.. show use what you tried and why you think it wont work..

Comment: I don't think your deletion problem has anything to do with the form being opened or closed. Your files are probably still in use by the process.

Comment: I imagine a Google search for "C# delete files" will show *some* examples of how to delete files.  (Hint: There's a `Delete()` method on the `File` object.)  If you're getting errors, we can help with that.  But you'd have to actually show the errors and the code which produces the errors.  Otherwise, how can anybody here possibly know what's wrong with your code?

Comment: I'll bet that you're using `Image`/`Bitmap` in the code. So, you must to release them, calling the `Dispose` method.

Comment: step through those events in [The Debugger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn)  Are they getting hit, are they doing what you think they should be doing?  If not describe the actual result.  If an exception gets thrown, tell us what the exception is.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov
Thanks for that tip. It helped me to delete the images during program runtime. But the main problem is i want to delete these image files from the hard disk when i close the form.

Comment: To delete files from the disk, you MUST release ALL resources that can capture them. It can be file streams, bitmaps, etc. Look in your code for all places where you could grab resources and dispose them. The operating system may still long to hold them, if you don't release them.

Comment: Whatever the problem is, you are not showing it in the question. There is nothing in the code you showed that would prevent the deletion of the files from the hard disk when you close the form.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation of the [Directory.GetFiles Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx). Perhaps that is a problem or perhaps the code you posted is inconsistent with your actual code.

I created a Windows Forms application and put two buttons on the form, a Create button and a Delete button.

The following is the code for the Create button:

```
string Name = string.Empty;
for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
    try
    {
        Name = Folder + "SO36922336-" + i.ToString() + ".txt";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Name);
        sw.WriteLine("File created using StreamWriter class.");
        sw.Close();
        sw.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message + "\r\n" + Name);
    }
}
```

The following is the code for the Delete button:

```
string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "SO36922336-*.txt");
foreach (string fn in Files)
{
    File.Delete(fn);
}
```

The code works for me. So either you are doing Directory.GetFiles incorrectly or the problem is in code that you did not show or both. You don't need to do the delete outside of the form.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to have the OS take care of those temporary files. To do so, call the [File.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143360.aspx) overload<sup>1)</sup> taking a [FileOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileoptions.aspx) argument, and pass `DeleteOnClose`. That way the file is automatically deleted by the system, once all handles to it are closed. Added bonus: If your application terminates due to a crash, the OS will still clean up the file after you.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *If you don't know what value to pass for the* bufferSize *parameter, just pick the default: 4096.*